# From which interaction term does the self-energy diagram of $\phi^4$ theory come?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, self-energy

In 4D, let us start with the normal-ordered product of free neutral scalar fields $:\phi^4:$.

Then, we can in fact write $$:\phi^4:=\sum_{i=0}^4 V_i$$ where each $V_i$ is an operator-valued distribution containing $i$ creation operators and $4-i$ annihilation operators.

Now, let us investigate the following diagram:

[image]

What I wonder is that, in the formal perturbative series of the S-matrix, which $V_i$'s contribute to this diagram at each vertex?

I am trying to follow the derivation of Feynman rules from Weinberg textbooks, and suspect that $V_4$ accounts for the left vertex. On the other hand, how about the right vertex?

Could anyone please clarify?